# Where NPM Install output goes? I cannot find it in stdout nor stderr

Tags: npm, stdout, npm-install, stderr, npm-cli

I am trying to get the output of the command `npm install` and show it in my cli module.

But I am getting only the result at the end, not the loading output with the progress bar.

Is maybe npm outputing in another place different from `stdout` and `stderr`?

This is my code in Typescript

```typescript
import * as cp from 'child_process';

const child = cp.spawn('npm', ['install', 'some-module']);
    
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
    process.stdout.write(chunk);
});
    
child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stderr.on('data', (chunk) => {
    process.stdout.write(chunk);
});
```

This is the only output I get at the end of the process:

```
added 154 packages, and audited 505 packages in 52s
```

Where the loading bar and all the rest of the output go? Why it is not in `stdout` or `stderr`?